# Mean of a variable

Tags: r, sum, mean

I have been trying to find the mean of a variable, but when I run the code it says: "length of the largest object is not a multiple of the length of the smallest object."

Here's the statement of the question: 
"What is the average number of assassination attempts (per year) among the countries that have experienced at least one assassination attempt?

Here's the dataset that is needed: 
leaders <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/leaders.csv")

Here's the code that I used:

```
avrn$avrnbr <- as.numeric(leaders$result == "wounded lightly","dies within a day after the attack",
                          "dies between a day and a week", "dies between a week and a month",
                          "dies, timing unknown", "survives, whether wounded unknown",
                          "not wounded",
                          "plot stopped",
                          "hospitalization but no permanent disability",
                          leaders$year == 1878:2001)
```

I tried to create a variable that measures the mean of assassinations per year.

Comment: There might be a couple of issues. One is: When trying to match to more than one values use `%in%` instead of `==`. See ?`%in%` for details. Another one: The different descriptions should be pasted into one vector using the `c(...)` construct.

Comment: (1) `as.numeric(a==b)` will give you the average of trues out of the sample, perhaps not what you mean. (2) `as.numeric("not wounded")` is `NA`, as is most of what you have in this command. Not knowing the logic that goes into the data itself is also something hindering our help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset contains information about an assassination attempt among leaders of a particular country. There are 250 records over the 124-year period from 1878 - 2001.

**Your question**: "What is the average number of assassination attempts (per year) among the countries that have experienced at least one assassination attempt?"

Every country in this dataset, by definition, has experienced at least 1 assassination attempt. So there is no need to subset or filter. Neither is it necessary to filter on the year as you had done. We just need to calculate the total number of assassination attempts (250) divided by the number of years *spanning* the data (124). **Answer**: 2.

---

Curiosity got the better of me. Which countries have the most unpopular leaders?

```
library(dplyr)

count(leaders, country) %>% arrange(-n)

# A tibble: 88 x 2
   country           n
   <chr>         <int>
 1 Japan            11
 2 Mexico           11
 3 France           10
 4 Russia           10
 5 United States     8
 6 Guatemala         7
 7 Egypt             6
 8 Iran              6
 9 Italy             6
10 Argentina         5
# ... with 78 more rows
```